# Counter in for-each, position() is not useful

Tags: xml, xslt

How to use a counter without use position() in XSLT?
For example:
XML

```
<product type="A" name="pepe"/>
<product type="B" name="paco"/>
<product type="A" name="Juan"/>
<product type="B" name="Edu"/>
<product type="A" name="Lauren"/>
```

I want to show all the types "A" in order with their number:

```
1.pepe
2.Juan
3.Lauren
```

The xsl will be something like that

```
<xsl:for-each select="./products">
<xsl:if test="./products/product/@type="A"">
                    <tr>
<xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
<xsl:value-of select="./product/@name"/>  
                    </tr> 
</xsl:if>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Why do you say "position() is not useful"? What exactly have you tried so far, and how does the output you're currently getting differ from what you need?

Comment: I added a xsl. Position() is not useful because it counts all the iterations of the for-each. I just want the numbers of the products type "A" without counting the type B as I showed in the solution. Sorry for my english :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `position()` function is context-sensitive - it gives you the position of the current node within the "current node list", i.e. the list of nodes extracted by the `select` expression of the current `for-each` or `apply-templates`.  So if you do something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="product">
  <xsl:if test="@type = 'A'">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="position()"/>: <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></li>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

then you will get `position()` values of 1, 3 and 5 because the `select` selects all five product elements.  But if instead you put the `@type` test in the `select` expression:

```
<xsl:for-each select="product[@type = 'A']">
  <li><xsl:value-of select="position()"/>: <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

then you will get positions 1, 2 and 3 because the `for-each` is only processing the three product elements whose `@type` is A, rather than all five of them.

---

In a more complex case where you really *do* need to process *all* the `product` elements (e.g. if you're doing something with the type A ones and something different with the type B ones, but need to keep the document order) then you'd need to do a trick with the `preceding-sibling::` axis, e.g.

```
<xsl:if test="@type = 'A'">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::product[@type = 'A']) + 1" />
</xsl:if>
```

to explicitly count the number of preceding `product` elements with the same `@type` as this one.